# Whenever I run my feature file of cucumber, the URL is not loaded

Tags: selenium, cucumber, bdd

Whenever I run the cucumber feature file, I get an assertion error that the URL doesn't load. But the same step destination if executed from TestNG is executed without error.

Please note I have a java binding

Comment: Are you running the feature file from an IDE or command line?

Comment: IDE@Grasshopper

Comment: post some code.